# targetFrame _blank MVSiteMapCOntrib

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, sitemap, mvccontrib, mvcsitemapprovider

Im using the MVC Contrib project to generate my menu system for an MVC site.

How does one generate attributes in your `<a href` tag based on your SiteMap. Ive managed to achieve this by specifying the `attributesToIgnore="target"` in my provider definition in my web.config and adding the attribute to my mvcSiteMapNode element in my sitemap file.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Hello World"
                    controller="Home"
                    action="Index"
                    changeFrequency="Always"
                    updatePriority="Normal"
                    target="_blank">
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

I then iterate through my SiteMap file pick of the attribute using

```
siteMapNode["target"]
```

and render it myself as `<a href="#" target="_blank" > </a>`. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more of your code, so that I could try to duplicate what you're attempting?  How are you setting up your provider in your web.config?  What do you have in your Controller and/or View?

Comment: Hey @Vito I added some additional info to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating a SiteMapNodeModel display template? That allows you to construct your anchor tag however you wish. I created one to specifically add a class to the anchor if the node was in the current path so that I could apply specific CSS.

Here is the razor partial view I use:

```
@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapNodeModel
@{   
    if (Model.IsCurrentNode && Model.SourceMetadata["HtmlHelper"].ToString() !="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MenuHelper")
{
        @Model.Title    
    }
    else if (Model.IsClickable)
    {
        <a href="@Model.Url" class="@(Model.IsInCurrentPath ? "current" : string.Empty)" target="@Model.TargetFrame" >@Model.Title</a>
    }
    else
    {
    @Model.Title
    }

}
```

The file, named "SiteMapNodeModel.cshtml" (razor) goes in Shared/DisplayTemplates. When asp.net Mvc rendors a SiteMapNodelModel it will automatically use this template.

Comment: ! Thats what I was look for, is it possible to do this without razor? Do you use the SiteMapHelperModel.ascx file instead?

Comment: Yes it would be possible using the default view engine syntax (as*x). The example that comes with the MvcSiteMapProvider uses this syntax and I converted it to razor since this is what I am using for my project.

Comment: Thank you figured it out a while back, thanks for your post though, worth the 50 points of rep ...